# How to correct handle Dialog.dismiss() inside Fragment using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, dialog, retrofit, retrofit2, dismiss

I'm using Retrofit 2 to make a POST request to my server inside a Fragment, like this:

```
Call<MyResponse> call = apiService.myPost(params);
call.enqueue(myCallback);

mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Working", "Working"", true);
```

I want to dismiss the ProgressDialog when the request is finished, as you can see here:

```
class myCallback {
    onResponse() {
       mProgress.dismiss();
    }
    onFailture() {
       mProgress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

However this approach does not work fine, because the user could rotate or  leave the current Activity, leading to this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1ec6c6d0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-513,242} not attached to window manager
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
       at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
       at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
```

How can I properly dismiss a Dialog in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dismiss the dialog when the Fragment detaches from its Activity, or add a check to see whether the Fragment is still attached. The example below calls [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) to check this.

```
onResponse() {
     if (isAdded()) {
         mProgress.dismiss();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Call<MyResponse> call = apiService.myPost(params);
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Repo> response) {
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }
});
```